# Probability: Drawing balls from boxes

Tags: probability

We have 2 round boxes and 4 square boxes. Every round box has 2 green and 3 blue balls. Every square box has 1 green and 3 blue balls. We random choose one box and random choose one ball.

1. What is the probability that choosen ball is blue?
2. What is the probability that choosen box is round if we know that choosen ball is blue?

My solution for (1) is $0,7$ and for (2) is $0,5$. Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: (a)P(blue)=no.of blue balls given n balls; (b)P(round given blue)=P(round and blue)/P(blue)

Comment: Your first one is correct.  $P(\text{blue})=\frac{7}{10}$  For the second one, it should be $\frac{2}{7}$.  Show us what you tried

Comment: @AlainRemillard: Oops! You are correct. My simulation was dividing the `round if blue` count by the total number of trials, rather than by the `total_blue` count. Sorry.

Comment: Both of the remaining answers are correct, you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the one that you think is the most helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Bayes' Rule question.

$P(blue)=P(blue\mid round)P(round)+P(blue\mid square) P(square)=\frac{3}{5}\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3}{4}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{7}{10}$

$P(round\mid blue)=\frac{P(blue\mid round)P(round)}{P(blue)}=\frac{1/5}{7/10}=\frac{2}{7}$.

Comment: last question: I have to draw this in tree diagram. Is this correct? http://i.imgur.com/qupaKn1.png

Answer (score 2):

The probability of choosing a round box is 2/6= 1/3.  **If** we choose a round box, the probability of choosing a blue ball is 3/5.  The probability of choosing a round box **and** a blue ball (1/3)(3/5)= 1/5.

The probability of choosing a square box is 4/6= 2/3.  **If** we choose a square box, the probability of choosing a blue ball is 3/4.  The probability of choosing a square box **and** a blue ball is (2/3)(3/4)= 2/4= 1/2.

The probability of choosing a blue ball without regard to which box is 1/5+ 1/2= 2/10+ 5/10= 7/10.

For the second problem I would do this.  Imagine doing this experiment 30000 times.  1/3(3000)= 1000 times you choose a round box.  Of those 1000 times, 3/5(1000)= 600 times you get a blue ball.  2/3(3000)= 2000 times you get a square box.  Of those 2000 times, 3/4(2000)= 1500 times you get a blue ball.  So you get a blue ball 600+ 1500= 2100 times.  Of those 2100 times, we chose it out of a round box 600 times.  The probability you originally chose a round box, given that you got a blue ball, is 600/2100= 2/7.